# Google charts problem with values on charts

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

Hey all can anyone help me with the problem i have with google charts.

The problem is numbers are not scaled 1, 2, 3, ... you can see on image on left side of chart.
[image]

JavaScript and PHP code

```php
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Data', 'Count' , 'Approved' , 'Drafted'],
        <?php
      $elements_text = ['Posts' , 'Categories', 'Users','Comments'];
      $element_count =[$post_count,$categories_count,$users_count,$comment_count];
      $element_published = [$published_posts,'0',$admins_count,$approved_comments_count];
      $element_drafted = [$drafted_posts,'0',$subscriber_count,$unapproved_comments_count];


      for($i =0; $i<4 ; $i++){
        echo "['{$elements_text[$i]}'" . "," . "'{$element_count[$i]}'" . "," . "'{$element_count[$i]}'" . "," . "'{$element_drafted[$i]}'],";
      }
         ?>


      ]);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Admin data',
          subtitle: 'Charst panel',
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
    }
</script>
```

You can see that 6 is less than 0 :D

Comment: If you have problems with the chart, shouldn't you be looking at the data used to make the chart and not some PHP code?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crucially, this is not how to pass data from PHP to JavaScript. Never under any circumstances try to build your own JSON or other such structures; it will never work consistently. Use `json_encode()` for this. In addition to properly escaping strings, it also ensures that integers are properly passed as such.

```php
<?php
$elements = [
    ["Data", "Count", "Approved", "Drafted"],
    ["Posts", $post_count, $published_posts, $drafted_posts],
    ["Categories", $categories_count, 0, 0],
    ["Users", $users_count, $admins_count, $subscriber_count],
    ["Comments", $comment_count, $approved_comments_count, $unapproved_comments_count],
];
?>
<script>
google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["bar"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    const elements = <?= json_encode($elements) ?>;
    const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(elements);
    const options = {chart: {title: "Admin data", subtitle: "Chart data"}};
    const chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("columnchart_material"));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
</script>
```

If you continue to have problems after fixing this code, I suggest you take a look at the data you're passing to the chart as it's likely not what you expect. Since your original code was repeating data from `$element_count[$i]` that's probably your problem.